# How to fetch data between two dates in oracle database without date field in the table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to get the data inserted in the last week. But there is no date/time field in the table. Is there any way to fetch the data.
Can sysdate or timestamp method help for fetching the data.

Thank you

Comment: It may not work for old records and not very accurate, but try `SELECT * FROM table
WHERE SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) between systimestamp - 5 and systimestamp;`

Comment: @GurwinderSingh, the result might be so misleading that I would hesitate to suggest this method at all.

Comment: @FDavidov You are absolutely right. It's better to create a column to keep track of insertions

Comment: What you need is a [Flashback Data Archive](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/flashback-data-archive-fda-enhancements-12cr1). The `as of scn` and `as of timestamp` are bound by [undo_retention](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/undo002.htm#ADMIN10180)

Comment: Indeed. The problem (as I understand) is that the OP already has data and he/she cannot deploy values into the existing records. Solution: Think twice before starting to write (`CREATE TABLE...`).

Comment: @Gurwinder Singh, what you have suggested is working, but as you said creating a timestamp column would be much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to analyze result of the query below:

```
select *
from v$sql vs join v$session vses
on vs.sql_id=vses.sql_id
where vses.last_load_time < vses.date_1 and last_load_date < date_2
and upper(sql_fulltext) like 'INSERT INTO%TABLE_NAME' or 'upper(sql_fulltext) like 'UPDATE%TABLE_NAME';
```